# Category Name Space Issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following extract of code to show markers on my map, with the custom marker colour determined by the category which it falls within.

```
var customIcons = {
            Artefact: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Coin: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Jewellery: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Prescious Metal: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };
```

The problem I'm having is with the last category, 'Prescious Metal'. For the life of me I can't get the script to work when there is a space between the words. I've tried adding ' ' which I thought may be a work around this, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys in JavaScript object literals must follow the variable naming convention, or be strings.  Putting quotes around it fixes the issue.

```
var customIcons = {
        "Artefact": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
        },
        "Coin": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
        },
        "Jewellery": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
        },
        "Prescious Metal": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
        }
        };
```

Comment: That's absolutely great. Many thnaks for your help. kind regards Chris